Error when trying to update ubuntu
I am getting the following errors when trying to update ubuntu:
sudo apt update
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates Release' does not 
have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by 
default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports Release' does not 
have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by 
default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

I found others running into this same "apt-secure(8)" issue but their fixes did not fix mine. Appreciate if anyone can give me some guidance here.
